# Position slider ui value at specific point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, slider

I'm looking for a way to position yardsticks at certain points. Slider picks up values from specified array [5000, 10000, 15000, 20000, 25000, 30000, 35000, 40000, 45000, 50000, 55000, 60000, 65000, 70000, 75000, 80000, 85000, 90000, 95000, 100000, 200000, 300000, 400000, 500000] and currently there is an equal gaps between steps. However I want to show certain steps at 5, 25, 50, 100 and 500 and position them at every 20% of slider length. Image below illustrates what I have in mind:

[Yardsticks positioned every 20%](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxhEg.jpg)

Looking for any ideas how to do this.

```js
$(function () {
  var sizes = [ "5,000", "10,000", "15,000", "20,000", "25,000", "30,000", "35,000", "40,000", "45,000", "50,000", "55,000", "60,000", "65,000", "70,000", "75,000", "80,000", "85,000", "90,000", "95,000", "100,000", "200,000", "300,000", "400,000", "500,000" ];
  $("#slider-range-max2").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#per").val(sizes[0] + ' IOPS');
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      $("#per").val(sizes[ui.value] + ' IOPS');
    }
  });

  $("#plus2").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max2").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max2").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max2").slider("value", value + step);
  });

  $("#minus2").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max2").slider("value")
    var ste
```

```css
.slider{
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  width: 90%;
  background: #333;
 /* -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #999;*/
  height: 15px;
  border-radius:10px;
  border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  margin-left:15px;
}

.slider .ui-slider-handle{
  position: absolute; 
  background: red;
  border-radius:25px;
  width:20px; 
  height:50px; 
  top: -16px;
  left: 50px;
  border-style:none;
  box-shadow:none ;

}
input[type=text]{
   border: 1px solid #333;
  -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
  -moz-border-radius: 25px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin-top:-15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  width:120px;
  color:#2A3137;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top:5px;
  margin-left:5px;
 }
.minus, .plus{
 display:inline-block;
 float:left;
    border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding:5px 10px;
  margin-top:-15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color:#e3e3e3;
  color:#333;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
   width:10px;
   margin-top:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="quote-input" class="slider-input">
      <div id="minus2" class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
       <input type="text" id="per" class="per slider-value">
        <div id="plus2" class="plus">+</div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="perVal" id="perVal"/>
    </div>
           <div style="clear:both"></div>
          <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="slider-range-max2" cl
```

Slider can be accessed in Fiddle [Slider in Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martynava/uu6yayho/)

Comment: You can do ALL of that, including setting up custom pips, custom range values, and it will spread out your increment values automatically for you along the X axis with noUISlider. No sense in doing lots of work someone else has already done for you.

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/